# How to integrate twitter,facebook into iPhone app ？

Tags: iphone, facebook, twitter

I want to put facebook,twitter,flickr into my iPhone app, so that users can easily login in and post message from my app easily.

Put the question here is to get some clues or existing works for this purpose.

After searching, I get some related works here
http://code.google.com/p/iphone-facebook-twitter-connect-easy-integration-tool/

What is the best one you used ?

Comment: To my question,one answer about facebook
http://amanpages.com/sample-iphone-example-project/facebookagent-easy-way-to-integrate-facebook-connect-in-iphone-apps-and-write-minimum-code-to-publish-feed-change-status/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a new open source project that provides support for both:

[ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com)

Comment: yah true...Sharekit doesn't work anymore! Do we have any alternative for it?

Answer (score 2):

This issues has already been discussed a lot in SO.Try to search SO before posting your query.

For Twitter try [MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine).

For facebook try [Facebook API](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk/)

For flickr try [objectiveflickr](http://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr)

Comment: Yes, I have searched some. As you know, I already have some options. But want to know what is the best one until now. That is what I want to talk about again. 
Thanks for your advice !

Answer (score 1):

Chk these

[Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/)

[Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/)