# Facebook user signup API for iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

Is there any Facebook user signup API available for iPhone?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146804/how-to-integrate-twitter-facebook-into-iphone-app

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific API available for new user creation ,

Instead you can call a Facebook Login Window through which there is link with signup - enable to create new user.