# How to share information to Facebook and Twitter?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter

I'd like to integrate the app with Facebook and Twitter. I.e. when the game is over, the user can click the 'share' button, then login facebook/twitter in the app, share the record in his wall after login dialog.

Two questions:

1. Shall I apply the API key for both Facebook and Twitter, for my app?
2. Since this feature shall be common for most apps, do you have any experiences on it? Or is there any shared library that can be used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate twitter,facebook into iPhone app ？](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146804/how-to-integrate-twitter-facebook-into-iphone-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at ShareKit, that helps sharing content across various social networks. Haven't tried it myself but heard a lot about it.

For Facebook you can also use the official FacebookAPI lib.

Comment: Yes, for Facebook, i found the API here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Answer (score 0):

You can find the below link that will help you.

http://getsharekit.com/

http://getsharekit.com/install/#download

https://github.com/ideashower/sharekit/

This above link its help you.

Comment: thanks, it looks that ShareKit is very commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

If you just plan to link to Twitter and FB Sharekit might be a bit too much.

Facebook integration is easy, just follow the tutorial on FB developpers site:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

For Twitter, I think that best think to do is rely on iOS native support that will be available in iOS 5 (details under NDA).

Comment: Thanks, for twitter, there will be big changes as you mentioned. Will it only works for iOS 5?

Comment: Yes. Twitter support is iOS 5 only.